# Error when installing marble for qt5: Could not find a package Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake

Tags: qt5, marble

I am trying to install marble for qt5 on ubuntu and I am following the steps here: https://marble.kde.org/sources.php
However, I am getting these errors when installing the qt marble version. Any idea how to get the  Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake package?

Command Line output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:78 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Script.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Script", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Script" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake
    qt5script-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Script" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Script_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Script" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Installing the qtscript5-dev should fix it.

Comment: What about on Debian Stretch?